# How can I interface with arduino mega2560 to detect the presence of a 48 V without pulling down the voltage by more than 0.1 V

Tags: arduino, step-down, input-impedance, powermosfet

[image: Circuit]

How can I interface with a microcontroller to detect presence of a 48 V supply with a source impedance of 10 kΩ without pulling down the voltage by more than 0.1 V?

I need to step down the output voltage (48V) at the drain of the IRFZ44N power MOSFET to within 5V so that it can be read by an Arduino without loading and causing the voltage to drop below 48V.

The MOSFET is acting as a switch. In the end I need to be able to tell if the switch is on or off based on the output at the drain terminal of the mosfet. How do I go about this?

Comment: What’s the issue with just a voltage divider?

Comment: No, just two resistors dividing 48 V down to 5 V + some margin. What are your requirements on load on the 48 V and what's the imput impedance of your menasurement?

Comment: No, it has not. What is your source impedance/how many uA/mA of load current can you spare from your 48 V supply? What is the imput impedance of your measurement at 5 V?

Comment: i have added an image. Please have a look at the first image. I'm measuring 5V using an arduino. So input impedance of an analog pin is 100Mohm

Comment: So you have 10 kohm source impedance or is R1 part of your attempt at a divider?

Comment: R1 is to limit current flow between drain and source only.

Comment: using the same mosfet to make another switch with gate as 48V is also not possible because the max gate voltage is +-20V

Comment: Please disregard what you have drawn and take a step back. Your 48 V source as it is, what is the source impedance from it and/or how much current can you spare for your measurement?

Comment: Clearly looking at OPs diagram has either using the fet a switch so the voltage is either 48, or some residual voltage from the resistance to ground. Or OPs using it as a variable voltage diver which in that case the accuracy going to be horrible so not sure why your on here being so anal about voltage drop. Using 1M ohm+ resistor driver will not cause significant voltage drop and the arduino ADC can easily trad that. Oh yes OP I hope your not using a radio UNO as its adc is not great compared to other models if you care so much. You could use another opamp to buffer if your really that worrid

Comment: No response from OP. VTC as unclear.

Comment: @winny I can spare in the order of a few Milli amps for measurement, as I do not want the 48v to drop

Comment: @Nick, your question should read, "How can I interface with a microcontroller to detect presence of a 48 V supply with a source impedance of 10 kΩ without pulling down the voltage by more than x V?" Your question doesn't make clear whether a digital read will do or if you want to measure the actual voltage - although I suspect that digital will suffice. Hit the edit link below your question ...

Comment: i have edited the question, description and circuit. Hope, you get it now.

Comment: So just use a voltage divider as originally suggested, what's the problem here? Is it VAC or something?

Comment: if i use a voltage divider, then the current limiting 10kohm resistor will also come into picture. Say i use 1kohm and 10kohm, then, the output voltage will be 11kohm/(11kohm+10kohm(current limiting))* 48V= 25.1V

Comment: "Say i use 1kohm and 10kohm, then, the output voltage will be 11kohm/(11kohm+10kohm(current limiting))* 48V= 25.1V" - but the load draws 0.5A at 48V, which is equivalent to 96 Ohms. What is the purpose of the 10k resistor and why does it have to be so large?

Comment: i have a 0.5Watt 10kohm resistor there to limit the current flow from drain to source.

Answer (score 3):

> I can spare in the order of a few Milli amps for measurement, as I do
>   not want the 48v to drop
>
> I'm measuring 5V using an arduino. So input impedance of an analog pin
>   is 100Mohm

<s>To be able to tell *how much* your 48 V will drop due to this, you must provide the source impedance of your 48 V rail.</s>

Non the less, if you can spare a few mA of current for the measurement and have 100 Mohm input impedance downstream, I would recommend the following:

This will consume just under 2 mA and give you about 20 % margin until you saturate your measurement.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFImUb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**EDIT:** With your updated information (for future reference here on EE.SE, please make sure not to sprinkle vital informaion in comments and include as much as you have in your original question), this above is my updated schematic. It will load your 48 V rail with about 45 uA, causing a <1% voltage drop across your 10 kohm source impedance.

Comment: i have dited the question, circuit and title. Hope it is clear now